# What does this C++ macro do (competitive programming)?

Tags: c++, macros

Original:

```
#define scan(x) do{while((x=getchar())<'0'); for(x-='0'; '0'<=(_=getchar()); 
x=(x<<3)+(x<<1)+_-'0');}while(0)
```

Expanded:

```
do {
    while ((x = getchar()) < '0');
    for (x -= '0'; '0' <= (_ = getchar());
        x = (x << 3) + (x << 1) + _ - '0');
} while (0)
```

I tried formatting it to understand it better. But, can someone explain how it works and the use of it.

Comment: I don't see a macro...

Comment: @Dragonthoughts presumably `#define X(_)` is the missing line.

Comment: @Dragonthoughts I have added the original one.

Comment: You mean what it does beyond obfuscating code?

Comment: You have indented your expanded version wrong. That might cause unnecessary confusion, for you or for others.

Comment: It makes your code fail the code review. Sadly competitive programming contests do not perform code reviews. I wish they did. I might hire more competitive programmers.

Answer (score 4):

It's reading characters from standard input and converting them to an integer.

This code

```
 x = (x << 3) + (x << 1) + _ - '0';
```

is equivalent to

```
 x = 10*x + (_ - '0');
```

It's a totally spurious optimisation because if `(x << 3) + (x << 1)` executes faster than `10*x` then the compiler will perform that transformation for you.

The macro also relies on a variable `_` having been declared somewhere. Presumably the name has been chosen to try and avoid a clash any other variable. It's another reason this macro is dubious, it isn't self-contained.

The rest of it is the same. It's the wrong way to program. Write clear understandable code and rely on the compiler to make micro-optimisations of the kind that are being performed here. In general the compiler is better at doing this kind of stuff than the programmer.

Comment: So, would you say it isn't useful to make faster programs?

Comment: That's exactly what I'm saying.

Comment: what does the "_" thing do ?

Comment: Unless you can make your main algorithms faster.